# Write down a sentence that is a contradiction if and only if the argument ‘X, therefore Y’ is valid

Tags: logic, argumentation

I came across this exercise in a past paper and cannot seem to wrap my head around it. How can a sentence be a contradiction with a valid argument?
I don't know an awful lot about sentence logic, so this might be trivial, but can anyone explain?

Comment: This is a puzzler. What was the exact question from the paper? It looks like the reader is supposed to find a sentence that satisfies the following: If and only if 'X therefore Y' is valid, then the sentence contradicts itself. The solution would also satisfy: If and only if the sentence contradicts itself, then 'X therefore Y' is valid. Was that the original question?

Comment: X, therefore not-Y

Comment: Write down a sentence that is a contradiction if and only if the argument ‘X, therefore Y’ is valid. That was the whole question. I understood it the way you did @MarkAndrews

Comment: X and not Y. This sentence is the contradictory of X -> Y.

Comment: "X, therefore Y" is a proposition, so calling it "valid" is a category mistake.  Propositions are true or false, inferences are valid or invalid.

Comment: p.s. "X -> Y", being a proposition, also cannot be an argument.

Comment: @mobileink No, I would say that "X, therefore Y" is an argument. The word "therefore" is more naturally understood to mean a meta-level consequence relation, not a first order connective. Also, propositions can be valid: it is standard usage to say that a valid proposition is one that is true in all interpretations.

Comment: @Bumble: the op clearly did not mean "logically valid".  that would be ridiculous, since X->Y is obviously not logically valid under any circumstance. besides, using "logically valid" as a synonym for "always true" is an unfortunate and abominable abuse of terminology.

Comment: @Bumble: if "therefore" is a "meta-level" connective, then please explain what X, therefore Y means, because i have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @mobileink The word "therefore" is often used to separate the premises of an argument from its conclusion. We might also think of it as the meta-level semantic consequence relation, which we might write as a double turnstile. Since we are talking about logic here, "valid" must mean logically valid: what other kind of validity would be relevant to a question about logic? And whether or not you find the term "valid proposition" abominable, it is still standard usage.

Comment: if you can answer my question, fine, if not, sayonara.

Comment: @Bumble "valid must mean logically valid"?  i think you need to do some more homework if you think logical validity is the only kind there is. i'm done here.

Comment: @mobileink No, if in "X therefore Y" X and Y are metavariables there are infinitely many sentences X and Y for which "X therefore Y" is valid in the sense that logicians describe valid axioms (i.e. theorems) of a logic.

Comment: I downvoted for two reasons: 1 i get no value from investing my time analyzing this and 2 you answer you own question which i don't understand. I'll certainly reverse the vote up if you can provide some value or insight or something interesting. As is what I am seeing here is useless. Please do enlighten me. What's the deal?

Comment: I also cannot grasp what the question asking. It needs more words.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, with regard to logic, something can be **valid** but not **sound**. Validity expresses the idea that the logical structure leads to the conclusion. If the premises are true, then the conclusion is **necessarily** true. That's what validity is supposed to regard.

That's not enough for an argument to be sound though. In order to be sound the *premises must also be true*.

SO,for example:

1. All men are mortal
2. Socrates is a man
   .:therefore socrates is mortal

The two premises (1 and 2) lead necessarily to the conclusion (.:). This is a valid argument. It is also sound because the premises are true as well.

That said, we could construct a structurally valid argument that is **not sound**.

1. All men are thin.
2. Socrates is a man.
   .: therefore socrates is thin.

The structure of this argument is valid; which is to say that *IF* the premises were true, the conclusion would necessarily be true.  But the premises **aren't** true and the conclusion is not true.

Answer (score 0):

How about (Y->(X->Y))&~(X->Y)